# Run SKAction x number of times

Tags: ios, for-loop, swift3, sprite-kit, skaction

I have an SKAction that essentially acts as a countdown timer for my game in sprite kit. To make it a timer though I put it in a for loop that ran 50 times. The actual delay on this action works, however the for loop seems to mess everything up. Any other options for a countdown timer in Spritekit would be fine as well. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
    let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration:0.1)
    let action = SKAction.run {
        time = time - 1
    }
    for _ in 1...50 {
        self.run(SKAction.sequence([wait,action]))
    }
```

Comment: What's the reasoning behind waiting 0.1s 50 times rather than just waiting 5s?

Comment: I would like to add intensity to the game by counting down like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use the for loop for this, you need to use `SKAction.repeat`. The reason being that the loop will execute `self.run(SKAction.sequence([wait,action]))` 50 times without waiting for `SKAction.sequence([wait,action])` to finish. Where as I assume what you really wanted was to execute `self.run` once and `SKAction.sequence([wait,action])` 50 times one after the other.

Here is an example I have made for you.

```
    let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration:0.1)
    let action = SKAction.run {
        time = time - 1
    }
    let repeatAction = SKAction.repeat(SKAction.sequence([wait,action]), count: 50)

    self.run(repeatAction)
```